# Append image style to an inline image in CKEditor

Tags: 8, wysiwyg, media

With views, for example, I'm able to set the image size which is to be loaded (using image styles). Is it in any way possible to do such thing in CKEditor?
At the moment, Drupal is loading the original image and scales it down in the browser. 
I need to set an image style so all the inline images are resized to a width of x pixels.

Answer (score 1):

Use [insert module](https://www.drupal.org/project/insert)

> Insert is a utility that makes inserting images and links to files
>   into text areas or WYSIWYGs much easier. It adds a simple
>   JavaScript-based button to FileField and ImageField widgets. When used
>   with ImageField and ImageCache, images may be inserted into text areas
>   with a specific ImageCache preset.
>
> This module was previously known as FileField Insert.
>
> Features
>
> ```
> Support for all major WYSIWYG editors, including tinyMCE, CKeditor, the WYSIWYG project (the recommended approach), and plain
> ```
>
> text areas.
>       Insert images using ImageCache presets
>       Maximum width setting for inserted images (for combined use with the Image Resize Filter module)
>       Per-field insert configuration

I used that on drupal 7 in several projects and it's what you want.I don't used Drupal 8 version yet,but hope works well.

Hopefully, in **Drupal >= 8.8** it's on the core.

https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/core/modules/media-library-module/embedding-media-with-ckeditor

Comment: Insert is still in beta for D8. It seems media and entity are more future-proof at this point.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of modules around:

- You really should use [entity_embed](https://www.drupal.org/project/entity_embed), it's quite out of the box, optionally with the [file_browser](https://www.drupal.org/project/file_browser) or even more sophisticated with the [media_entity](https://www.drupal.org/project/media_entity). (Could also be used in combination with core's [responsive images](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/mobile-guide/responsive-images-in-drupal-8))
- [Layouter](https://www.drupal.org/project/layouter) let's you insert one file in a layout, choosing the image style ..  [Insert](https://www.drupal.org/project/paragraphs) has a similar approach. (see answer from @zhilevan)

  > I'm not so friend with this approach, as it can be messed up by the user while re-editing.
- [IMCE](https://www.drupal.org/project/imce) is the simpler approach, but not automated, not image styles, so uploaded images, need to be thumb nailed.

---

And a different approach would be to use [paragraphs](https://www.drupal.org/project/paragraphs). **Not (only) directly in but combinable with CKeditor**.

Answer (score 0):

In Drupal 8 you can employ the Media module and Entity Embed suite of modules. This makes embedding media more Drupal native in CKEditor - and one of the things you can do is select which view mode to render the media in.

This view mode configuration can set which image style to use on its field formatter display.

Therefore, you can create a couple of view modes for inserting media and have those map to image styles in different use cases. It makes it easy for the user, all they have to do is select an option when embedding.